# How do I map a column to a complex type in EF4 using code first CTP5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

Having bumped into the of the lack of `enum` property support in Entity Framework 4 I discovered this article which describes a workaround:

> [Entity Framework 4.0 Beta 1 – POCO Enum support?](http://devtalk.dk/CommentView,guid,d5dccc2a-5723-49b4-97d1-bf759b7f592d.aspx)

How do I express the mapping of a database column to the `OrderStatusWrapper` (as described in the article) in code rather than in the designer?

**Update:**

Based on the answers provided, I hadn't realised that I needed to replace the `OrderStatus` enum with the `OrderStatusWrapper` type, i.e.

Instead of:

```
public class Order 
{
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

I should be using:

```
public class Order 
{
    public OrderStatusWrapper Status { get; set; }
}
```

This gets me a bit further, however upon executing the following code:

```
// OrderContext class defined elsewhere as:
// public class OrderContext : DbContext
// {
//   public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
// }
using(OrderContext ctx = new OrderContext())
{
    Order order = new Order { Status = OrderStatus.Created; }
    ctx.Orders.Add(order);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The following exception is raised (trimmed for brevity):

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            Message=Invalid column name 'Value'.
```

The database column is named `Status`. I tried decorating the `Status` property with:

`[Column("Status")]`

then

`[Column("Status"), TypeName("OrderStatus")]`

and

`[Column("Status"), TypeName("OrderStatusWrapper")]`

But this doesn't resolve this exception.

I also tried removing the `Column` attribute and doing this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
      .Property(p => p.OrderStatus)
      .HasColumnName("OrderStatus");
}
```

But I get the following compile error:

*Error  1   The type 'ConsoleApplication1.OrderStatusWrapper' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'  [snipped path]*

Comment: Check my post for a 2nd edit and hopefully the answer you seek

Comment: I closed this because EF won't have proper enum support until EF5.0/.NET 4.5 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx). Also CTP5 has long since gone making the question redundant.

Answer (score 3):

in the context file write this:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ComplexType<OrderStatusWrapper>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

it should work.

EDIT:

```
public class Order
{
     public...
     ...
     public OrderStatusWrapper OrderStatus { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = _context.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderStatus == OrderStatus.ReadyForShipping);

    _context.Orders.Add(new Order{ ..., OrderStatus = OrderStatus.Shipped });

    ...;
}
```

if you did as that example shows along with that small piece of code i showed the above (until EDIT:) should work as expected.

EDIT nr2:
If our wrapper looks like this:

```
public class OrderStatusWrapper
{
    private OrderStatus _status;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)_status; }
        set { _status = (OrderStatus)value; }
    }
    public OrderStatus EnumValue
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; }
    }
    public static implicit operator
         OrderStatusWrapper(OrderStatus status)
    {
        return new OrderStatusWrapper { EnumValue = status };
    }

    public static implicit operator
        OrderStatus(OrderStatusWrapper statusWrapper)
   {
       if (statusWrapper == null) return OrderStatus.OrderCreated;
       else return statusWrapper.EnumValue;
   }
}
```

The database takes the name of the property Value, so if you change that property name to Status, the column in the database would change to Status.

Comment: But you haven't provided any code to express the mapping between the OrderStatus column and the OrderStatusWrapper. This doesn't work on its own.

Comment: the entity would use the OrderStatusWrapper type and your OrderStatus would work as shown in the example, by adding modelBuilder.ComplexType it should accept the int value of the enum into the column in the database (if insert/update is made), this is the only extra code i used for it to work.

Comment: Ah ha, I hadn't realised I needed to replace `OrderStatus` with `OrderStatusWrapper` in the order POCO. Can you have a look at my update? Appreciated.

Comment: Ok...I see what's going on, buy why won't it let me remap that. ps: +1 for sticking with me on this :)

Comment: It has to do with the kind of type ObjectStatusWrapper is, had it been value type instead of a reference type it would've compiled with modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Property(p => p.OrderStatus).HasColumnName("OrderStatus"); but then you would receive System.InvalidOperationException stating that it hasn't been declared on the entity. I can't help much more than this since my knowledge kind of lacks the exact details but I'm sure that you or someone else will be able to find that answer.

Comment: @joakim - No problem, I appreciate very much the time you've spent on this. I learned a hell of a lot over the 24hrs, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following code is how the mappings looks like in Code First CTP5. In this case Code First will automatically recognize `OrderStatusWrapper` as a complex type due to a concept called *Complex Type Discovery* that works based on the *Reachability Convention*. You don't even need to use `ComplexTypeAttribute` or the `ComplexType<T>()` fluent API to explicitly register OrderStatusWrapper as a complex type.

For more info please take a look at this post:

**[Entity Association Mapping with Code First CTP5: Complex Types](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx)**

#### Update:

Due to a bug in CTP5, if you want to have a custom column name for your complex type properties (e.g. [Orders].[Status] for OrderStatusWrapper.Value in DB), then you have to explicitly mark it with `[ComplexType]`:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }               
    public OrderStatusWrapper Status { get; set; }
}    

[ComplexType]
public class OrderStatusWrapper 
{
    private OrderStatus _status;

    [Column(Name="Status")]
    public int Value {
        get { return (int)_status; }
        set { _status = (OrderStatus)value; }
    }
    public OrderStatus EnumValue {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; }
    }
}

public enum OrderStatus
{
    OrderCreated,
    OrderPayed,
    OrderShipped
}
```

Since you are working with an existing database, you can optionally switch off metadata table in database as well:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions
                .Remove<System.Data.Entity.Database.IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Comment: @Morteza - can you have a look at my update?  Appreciated.

Comment: I did and I cannot reproduce the exception you are getting. Mine works correctly. Code First will create a column name which exactly matches the complex type's property names (in this case *Value*), so I am a bit surprised that yours named Status. Can you post your full object model please, so I can see what's going on in there?

Comment: @morteza - I'm using an existing table in the DB and didn't allow code first to create it. I thought you could remap columns and properties?ps: +1 for sticking with me on this :)

Comment: @Kev: You bet you can :). I updated my answer to show you how. Basically, I manually change my DB column name to Status, and then change the column name for *Value* property with data annotations. It's now working with no problem and I am able to insert into the order table from my code first application. Please have a look.

Comment: I still want to point out that it still is possible to just change the name of Value to the name of the column in the database and it should work as expected even without [Column(Name="Status")]

Comment: @Joakim: Yep, that's another option.