# What is the best way to assign object with enumeration type in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, enumeration

I am fairly new to entity framework and I want to know what is the best approach to assign enumeration field to an object.

I want to write:

```
myObject.Status = Status.Active;
```

Shall I do:

```
myObject.Status = _context.myObjects.First(x=>x.Status.StatusId == Status.ActiveId);
```

and define

```
public partial class Status
{
     public const int ActiveId = 1;
}
```

or can I do something like:

```
public partial class Status
{
     public static Status Active = new Status(1, "Active");
}
```

which works out as

```
myObject.Status = Status.Active;
```

Or 3rd option can be just to forgot about mapping status into entity framework and just use Id on domain objects

```
myObject.StatusId = Status.Active.Id;
```

Can you let me know what is the best practice or simply what do you prefer yourself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered a question regarding enum here:
[How do I map a column to a complex type in EF4 using code first CTP5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484370/how-do-i-map-a-column-to-a-complex-type-in-ef4-using-code-first-ctp5/4484457#4484457)

this would allow you to use a complex type to map against an enumeration and is the way i prefer it.

Hope this helps.